# Better way to convert several instance variables into hash with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, instance-variables, symbols

I'm getting a response in the format of

```
 #<Response:0x000...   @first = "Charlie", @last=Kelly, ....
```

and I need to turn this into a hash (for active merchant). Currently I am looping through the variables and doing this:

```
response.instance_variables.each do |r|
  my_hash.merge!(r.to_s.delete("@").intern => response.instance_eval(r.to_s.delete("@"))) 
end
```

This works, it will produce `{:first = "charlie", :last => "kelly"}`
, but it seems a bit hacky and unstable. Is there a better way to do this ?

edit: I just realized I can use instance_variable_get for that second part of that equation, but that still leaves the main problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails has a method on `Object` called `instance_values` for just this. Here's the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c20838596bcb40bf1590f27f6ba735d0a5f4fe8f/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables.rb#L12).

```
class C
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end
end

C.new(0, 1).instance_values # => {"x" => 0, "y" => 1}
C.new(0, 1).instance_values.symbolize_keys # => {:x => 0, :y => 1}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can force the first value into a symbol instead of a string ? I can't touch the code that's receiving this, and strings aren't working.

Comment: Sure, `.symbolize_keys`: `obj.instance_values.symbolize_keys` should get you going!

Comment: Aww perfect man. I started to re-write that instance_values method but this is way easier. Grazie.

Comment: No problem, Rails usually has helpers for this kinda stuff, you just have to dig. Happy coding!